# Finding phase of fundamental from autocorrelation

Tags: phase, autocorrelation

I have some code, shown below that I have been using to find the fundamental of a guitar string.  After this function is called, I go thru the real buffer and find the peak, whose location gives me the period of the fundamental. Now I have a need to find the phase of the fundamental in relation to the start of the buffer.  Is there a way to find this phase from the info available in the code?

If this is not possible, is there a better algorithm to find both the fundamental and it's phase?

```
void AutoCorrelate(int real[],int imag[],int N,int sine[]){

fftTwiddle(real, imag, N);
fftForward(real,imag,N,sine);



for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    int h;
    unsigned int l;

    MACS(h,l,real[i],real[i],0,0);
    MACS(real[i],l,imag[i],imag[i],h,l);

    imag[i] = 0;

}

fftTwiddle(real, imag, N);
fftInverse(real,imag,N,sine);}
```

Comment: have a look to this question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9514/how-do-i-get-the-phase-angle-from-cross-correlation

Comment: That is interesting but is comparing the phase between two signals.  The only way I can think of using this is to recreate a reference signal at the fundamental frequency and use the window on this signal where I think the original signal is.  I didn't explain that well, but this method seems dodgy and subject to drift error.